# tikz viewport/clipping

Tags: tikz-pgf

So I'm building a "flipbook animation" using tikz. Where each tikzpicture is a single page, and objects should be *aligned* across different pages.

Now, the problem I'm running into is -- depending on the size / location of border objects, the size of my tikzpicture changes, and as a result, it's placement in the page also changes.

Is there someway to tell Tikz the follows:

I want you to

- render everything in the rectangular region with x1 <= x <= x2, and y1 <= y2 < y2
- always output a picture of size (x2-x1) x (y2-y1)

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
\clip (x1, y1) rectangle (width, height);
```

Comment: +1. You can apply this code to all your tikzpictures by using something like `\tikzset{
 every picture/.style={
  execute at begin picture={
   \clip (0,0) rectangle (5,2); 
  }
 }
}`. That way, you only have to change the values in one place in case you want a different viewport.

Comment: Note that the second pair of coordinates is not the width and height of your viewport but the pair of coordinates where the rectangle ends. For example, when you want to have a square viewport with `(0,0)` at the center and 2 units in each direction, you'd write: `\clip (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2);`